SwiftUI Firestore: Maintain List Position When Disabling Unread Filter
I'm working on a SwiftUI app that displays a filtered list of items from Firestore. I'm trying to maintain the list position when specifically disabling the unread filter, while keeping the regular "reset to top" behavior for all other filter changes.
What I've tried so far:

First attempt - Using timestamp:
func fetchInitialData() {
if showUnreadOnly {
lastVisibleTimestamp = items.first?.timestamp
unreadFilterJustDisabled = true
}
 var query = db.collection("collection")
     .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

 // Apply filters...

 if !showUnreadOnly && unreadFilterJustDisabled && lastVisibleTimestamp != nil {
     query = query.whereField("timestamp", isLessThanOrEqualTo: lastVisibleTimestamp!)
 }

}


Second attempt - Using document reference:
private var lastVisibleItem: Item?

func fetchInitialData() {
    if showUnreadOnly {
        lastVisibleItem = items.first
        unreadFilterJustDisabled = true
    }
    
    if !showUnreadOnly && unreadFilterJustDisabled && lastVisibleItem != nil {
        db.collection("collection").document(lastVisibleItem!.id).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot, snapshot.exists else { return }
            var positionedQuery = query.start(atDocument: snapshot)
            // ... continue with query
        }
    }
}

Current behavior:
The page number is maintained when disabling the unread filter
However, the list jumps to a different position instead of staying at the current item
Navigation to previous/next pages works correctly for all other filter changes
Expected behavior:
When disabling the unread filter, the list should maintain its position at the current item
All other filter changes should reset to the first page as they currently do
Previous/next page navigation should work correctly in all cases
Technical details:
Using SwiftUI and Firebase Firestore
Items are ordered by timestamp (descending)
Pagination implemented with limit() and start(afterDocument:)
Multiple filter options (unread, category, etc.)

Anyone? This should definitely be possible.
